# How to check the time is overlap with the exist record in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

For a booking system,

the booking record is store like this:

```
start_time (timeStamp)
duration (int)
```

It is in **hour** basis so the duration means how many hour is the booking. So , when I add a booking record, I would like to check whether the time interval is exist already (notice that overlap part of the pervious booking time also not allow).

I would like to write a SQL to select the data that is overlap, so if count row is 0 , then that means it is not overlap and allow to insert to table

Attempted something like

```
$start = $_POST['start'];
$duration = $_POST['duration'];

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM booking WHERE $start >= start_time AND  end_time_from_post <= end_time_from_exist_record
```

so the only problem seems to be to get the endtime, thanks for helping.

Comment: endtime - you mean `$_POST['start'] + $_post['duration']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to do an aggregation.  You can just check the returned result set for any row (in this case, it makes little difference, because there is presumably 0 or 1 rows, but in other similar situations aggregation is unnecessary overhead).

Two periods overlap if one begins before the second ends and the first ends after the second starts:

```
select 1
from booking
where $start <= date_add(start_time, interval duration hour) and
      date_add($start, interval $duration hours) >= start_time;
```

Note:  depending on your definition of "overlap", these might be strict inequalities.

Comment: overlap means whether the posting record is inside (exactly the same or part of) the time interval of existing records

Comment: @user3538235 . . . It is unclear whether this includes the end points.  That is the point of my comment.

Comment: let's say there is a new record from 2016-1-4 (3pm - 5pm), so for 2016-1-4, the booking end in 3pm / start at 5pm is not overlap, but if existing booking is 2pm - 4pm then it is overlap

Comment: any special case concern? please feel free to point out that, thanks for your helping